# On page load ,using JQuery how can i create a checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code creates a table loaded with values,
so everytime the row is created i want a checkbox on that row to be on first column.

```
var LoadLabels = function (data) {
    var CableInfos = eval(data);
    var newContent = '';
    var currentState = Hesto.Html.SaveTableState('#ScannedLabelList');

    if (CableInfos.length != 0) {
        $.each(CableInfos, function (i, item) {
            var sideFlag = item.KeepSideFlag;
            newContent += Hesto.Html.StsrtTR(); This is the column     where i wanna load my checkboxes
            newContent += Hesto.Html.StartTR(item.Serial, null);
            newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD(item.Serial, null);
            newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD(item.KanbanNumber, null,   null);
            newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD(item.CustomerNumber,   null, null);
            newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD(item.Description, null,    'centerAlign');
            newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD(item.Quantity, null);
        //  newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD('<input id="deleteRow"     type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)">', null);
            newContent = Hesto.Html.EndTR(newContent);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could append the checkbox markup to your newContent string:

```
$("newContent").append("<input type=checkbox name=" + Hesto.Html.StsrtTR() value=" + Hesto.Html.StsrtTR() + ">"Checkbox
```